# RecyclerView scrolling very slow with NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a RecyclerView with a NestedScrollView and the recycler view scrolling is very very slow. Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

After googleing and searching in Stack Overflow, i got this solution:

```
mMyRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

But it does not improve the scroll speed in my case, please help.

This is my xml code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    tools:context="fragment.HomeFrg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/ns1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                            android:id="@+id/card_background_new_design"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            app:cardElevation="5dp"

                            >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <LinearLayout

                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:weightSum="1">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/bestdeal"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                        android:padding="5dp"
                                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                                        android:text="DEALS"
                                        android:visibility="gone"
                                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                        android:textSize="12sp"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/viewall"
                                        android:visibility="gone"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                        android:gravity="end"
                                        android:padding="5dp"
                                        android:text="View All"
                                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                        android:textSize="12sp"
                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                </LinearLayout>

                                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_page2"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                                     android:paddingTop="10dp"
                                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homefrgMsg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/nonetwork"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar_home_frg" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Valyangadi.com&hl=en) is my app on google play store, for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this when you call your Linear layout manager

```
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false){
                @Override
                public boolean canScrollVertically() {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but try RecyclerView height match_parent to wrap_content